# Proving that a basis exists for a vector Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

let $P=span${$\vec{a_1}, \vec{a_2}$} be a plane in $\Bbb{R^4}$ and let $S$ be a subspace such that $S=$ {$\vec{x} \in\Bbb{R^4}|\vec{x} \cdot \vec{a_1}=0, and, \vec{x} \cdot \vec{a_2}=0 $} how would you prove that there exist $\vec{a_3}, \vec{a_4} \in \Bbb{R^4}$ such that {$\vec{a_3}, \vec{a_4}$} is a basis for $S$

Comment: Note that your proposed basis is not actually a basis for $S$, because those vectors aren't even in $S$.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot choose $\vec{a_3}=\vec{a_1}$ because $\vec{a_1}\not\in S$, because $\vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{v_1}\ne 0$. Similar for $\vec{v_4}$.

How it is actually proven depends on what you can assume is already known. One way is to:

- Take the basis $\{\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}\}$,
- Extend it to a basis $\{\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}, \vec{v_3}, \vec{v_4}\}$ for $\mathbb R^4$,
- Apply the Gramm-Schmidt algorithm to this basis, and this will give you an orthonormal basis $\{\vec{v'_1}, \vec{v'_2}, \vec{v'_3}, \vec{v'_4}\}$.

Now it is easy to prove that $\operatorname{span}(\vec{v'_1}, \vec{v'_2})=\operatorname{span}(\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}) = P$, and $\operatorname{span}(\vec{v'_3}, \vec{v'_4})=S$, so as the basis of $S$ you can take $\{\vec{v'_3}, \vec{v'_4}\}$.

My problem here is whether I can assume you are already familiar with Gramm-Schmidt algorithm and with this construction, or is this problem a sort of introduction to that material.

Comment: I am not familiar with the algorithim

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt It would be an easy cop-out for me to just point to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process ... However, the question remains: what sort of tools in linear algebra and particularly in inner product spaces have you already got? What can I assume you already know?

Comment: I was thinking of considering the 2 cross products $\vec{a_3}=\vec{a_1}\times\vec{a_2}$ and $\vec{a_4}=\vec{a_2}\times\vec{a_1}$ but im not sure if these would be linearly independent

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt You don't have cross product in $\mathbb R^4$: you have it in $\mathbb R^3$. So I think this is not going to be fruitful. Also, in $\mathbb R^3$ this would give you $\vec{a_4}=-\vec{a_3}$.

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt I will leave my answer here, even if it is not helpful to you, as a record of this conversation, and will try to think how you can prove what you are interested in - in a much more elementary way.

Comment: would't $S$ just the be the set of all vectors orthogonal to the plane?

Comment: @Skrrrrrtttt Indeed, in a $4$-dimensional space such as $\mathbb R^4$ $S$ would be a ($2$-dimensional) plane orthogonal to the $2$-dimensional plane $P$, and their intersection would be only $\{0\}$, just like in a $2$-dimensional space $\mathbb R^2$ you can have two *lines* (i.e. $1$-dimensional spaces) that are orthogonal to each other and intersect at the origin... But you said somewhere you are not familiar with dimensions, so I tried to steer clear of mentioning them...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72418/discussion-between-skrrrrrtttt-and-user8734617).

Comment: what does  $\vec{v'_4}$ mean?